# error must be of type array, null given in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to validate data through laravel using validator and also I inserted it to table called offers and I am sure it is true and also I use it to validate
and here is my code
**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Front\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::namespace('Front')->group(function(){
    Route::get('users',[UserController::class,'showAdminName']);
});
Auth::routes(['verify' =>true]);

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('verified');

Route::get('fillable',[\App\Http\Controllers\CrudController::class,'getOffers']);

Route::group(['prefix'=>'offers'],function(){
//    Route::get('store',[CrudController::class,'store']);
    Route::get('create',[CrudController::class,'createview']);
    Route::post('store',[CrudController::class,'store']);
});
```

**CrudController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Offer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    public function getOffers(){
        return Offer::select('id','name')->get();
    }

    public function createview(){
        return view('offers.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        // validate data
        $validate = Validator::make($request->all,[
            'name' => 'required|min:5|max:10|unique:offers,name',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'details' => 'required'
        ]);
        // insert
        Offer::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'details' => $request->details,
        ]);
        return back()->with('offer_created','Saved succesfully');
    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Try laravel</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/338515/pexels-photo-338515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260); background-size: cover; ">
    <div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                ADD OFFER
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if(Session::has('offer_created'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ Session::get('offer_created')  }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('offers\store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Offer Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        </div>
                        @error('name')
                            <div class="text-danger">
                                {{  $message  }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Offer Price</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="price">
                        </div>
                        @error('price')
                        <div class="text-danger">
                            {{  $message  }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Offer details</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="details">
                        </div>
                        @error('details')
                        <div class="text-danger">
                            {{  $message  }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-lpyLfhYuitXl2zRZ5Bn2fqnhNAKOAaM/0Kr9laMspuaMiZfGmfwRNFh8HlMy49eQ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it give me this error

> Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of
> type array, null given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\starter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
> on line 261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer pointed out, the technical solution is to call `$request->all()` instead of referring to `$request->all`.

However, I would like to explain the error message, because that's what you need to understand in order to be able to fix similar issues in the future. The error message tells you that there is a function whose first parameter expects an array to be passed, yet, instead of that `null` is passed. You have the following options to consider:

- you can avoid calling the function when the parameter differs from the type
- you can modify the type expectations of the function
- you can convert your parameter into the correct type

Answer (score 0):

try to make it $request->all (to $request->all()